# Как правильно ходить между viewControllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, архитектура, view, swift3

Как правильно ходить между `viewControllers`, чтобы  у них каждый раз заново перегружались `viewDidLoad` и при уходе с контроллера он умирал и убирался из памяти.
В проекте использую много segue  и переходов между сторибордами

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toDocDetail" {

        }
    }



let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "DetailOrderSB", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailOrderVC") as! DetailOrderVC
            vc.orderID = cell_data!.id
            vc.statusID = cell_data!.statusId
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

при закрытии использую или просто переход по сеге или `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

но столкнулся с проблемой, что таблицы и разные `view` стали сильно зависать после нескольких переходов между контроллерами,
`NavigationViewController` не использую,
есть только `ViewController`

[image]

Может кто-то объяснить, как правильно ходить по всему этому и не потерять логику и ресурсы девайса?
Может что-то почитать есть такое?

Comment: вы б может весь проект выложили. проще будет, чем так гадать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу с вашей логикой никаких проблем, разве что не используя UINavigationController вы усложняете себе жизнь (однако у вас могут быть свои причины, не спорю).

Можете проверить через дебаггер памяти - при дисмиссе контроллера он должен умирать, если на него нет сильных ссылок. Скорее всего, у вас маломощный компьютер (Air или виртуалка) и на реальном устройстве проблем с долгой загрузкой вы не заметите.

Comment: У меня мак про 15" 16 гб оперативки, не в железе проблема

Comment: Таких  подобных сторибордов 4 в проекте

Comment: И ещё делаю переходы в коде

Comment: @VolodymyrSlipak воспользуйтесь Debug Memory Graph и посмотрите, умирают ли исчезающие контроллеры. Если да, то я сдаюсь и проблема в другом. Если нет, ищите ссылки на контроллеры - при модальном показе vc ответственность за управление памятью контроллеров лежит на вас (поэтому я говорил об усложнении жизни без navigation controller)

Comment: Что лучше использовать при сеге в сториборде?  E.g push или  present Modal?

Comment: Лучшие практики Apple такие: модальный переход для единичного действия с серьёзными последствиями, после которого будет произведен переход назад (классический пример - после нажатия Add, вылезает vc с кнопкой Cancel в navigation bar'e. Ясно дает понять, что нужно заполнить всю эту форму или уходить). Иначе - использовать push (если посмотреть на приложения Apple, modal там придется еще поискать).

Comment: понял, спасибо большое!